# Tkinter 1 Player Tetris game

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, tkinter, tetris

## README.md

**Tetris game**

I am working towards making a Tetris game where you can challenge an AI. Multiple parts have been finished, but a lot is still under construction. However I would like an intermediate review. The code I will post is a fully working 1 player Tetris game made with python3.6 & tkinter. If you are interested, [Check the full github online.](https://github.com/Ludisposed/Tetris/)

**Controls**

- To change rotation of the current Piece  <kbd>w</kbd>
- To move Left  <kbd>a</kbd>
- To move Right  <kbd>d</kbd>
- Hard drop (The piece will fall down instantly)  <kbd>s</kbd>

**Features**

- See the next piece
- Hard drop
- Multiple rows cleared at once give more score
- [! Missing] Update in speed after certain amount of time/blocks

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import Canvas, Label, Tk, StringVar, Button, LEFT
from random import choice, randint

class GameCanvas(Canvas):
    def clean_line(self, boxes_to_delete):
        for box in boxes_to_delete:
            self.delete(box)
        self.update()

    def drop_boxes(self, boxes_to_drop):
        for box in boxes_to_drop:
            self.move(box, 0, Tetris.BOX_SIZE)
        self.update()

    def completed_lines(self, y_coords):
        cleaned_lines = 0
        y_coords = sorted(y_coords)
        for y in y_coords:
            if sum(1 for box in self.find_withtag('game') if self.coords(box)[3] == y) == \
               ((Tetris.GAME_WIDTH - 20) // Tetris.BOX_SIZE):
                self.clean_line([box
                                for box in self.find_withtag('game')
                                if self.coords(box)[3] == y])

                self.drop_boxes([box
                                 for box in self.find_withtag('game')
                                 if self.coords(box)[3] < y])
                cleaned_lines += 1
        return cleaned_lines

    def game_board(self):
        board = [[0] * ((Tetris.GAME_WIDTH - 20) // Tetris.BOX_SIZE)\
                 for _ in range(Tetris.GAME_HEIGHT // Tetris.BOX_SIZE)]
        for box in self.find_withtag('game'):
            x, y, _, _ = self.coords(box)
            board[int(y // Tetris.BOX_SIZE)][int(x // Tetris.BOX_SIZE)] = 1
        return board
    def boxes(self):
        return self.find_withtag('game') == self.find_withtag(fill="blue")

class Shape():
    def __init__(self, coords = None):
        if not coords:
            self.__coords = choice(Tetris.SHAPES)
        else:
            self.__coords = coords

    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self.__coords

    def rotate(self):  
        self.__coords = self.__rotate()

    def rotate_directions(self):
        rotated = self.__rotate()
        directions = [(rotated[i][0] - self.__coords[i][0],
                       rotated[i][1] - self.__coords[i][1]) for i in range(len(self.__coords))]

        return directions

    @property
    def matrix(self):
        return [[1 if (j, i) in self.__coords else 0 \
                 for j in range(max(self.__coords, key=lambda x: x[0])[0] + 1)] \
                 for i in range(max(self.__coords, key=lambda x: x[1])[1] + 1)]

    def drop(self, board, offset):
        # print("\n\n\n")
        # print('\n'.join(''.join(map(str, b)) for b in board))
        # print("\n\n\n")
        off_x, off_y = offset
        # print(off_x,off_y)
        last_level = len(board) - len(self.matrix) + 1
        for level in range(off_y, last_level):
            for i in range(len(self.matrix)):
                for j in range(len(self.matrix[0])):
                    if board[level+i][off_x+j] == 1 and self.matrix[i][j] == 1:
                        return level - 1
        return last_level - 1  

    def __rotate(self):
        max_x = max(self.__coords, key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
        new_original = (max_x, 0)

        rotated = [(new_original[0] - coord[1],
                    new_original[1] + coord[0]) for coord in self.__coords]

        min_x = min(rotated, key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
        min_y = min(rotated, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
        return [(coord[0] - min_x, coord[1] - min_y) for coord in rotated]

class Piece():
    def __init__(self, canvas, start_point, shape = None):
        self.__shape = shape
        if not shape:
            self.__shape = Shape()
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.boxes = self.__create_boxes(start_point)

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self.__shape

    def move(self, direction):
        if all(self.__can_move(self.canvas.coords(box), direction) for box in self.boxes):
            x, y = direction
            for box in self.boxes:
                self.canvas.move(box,
                                 x * Tetris.BOX_SIZE,
                                 y * Tetris.BOX_SIZE)
            return True
        return False

    def rotate(self):
        directions = self.__shape.rotate_directions()
        if all(self.__can_move(self.canvas.coords(self.boxes[i]), directions[i]) for i in range(len(self.boxes))):
            self.__shape.rotate()
            for i in range(len(self.boxes)):
                x, y = directions[i]
                self.canvas.move(self.boxes[i],
                                 x * Tetris.BOX_SIZE,
                                 y * Tetris.BOX_SIZE)

    @property
    def offset(self):
        return (min(int(self.canvas.coords(box)[0]) // Tetris.BOX_SIZE for box in self.boxes),
                min(int(self.canvas.coords(box)[1]) // Tetris.BOX_SIZE for box in self.boxes))

    def predict_movement(self, board):
        level = self.__shape.drop(board, self.offset)
        min_y = min([self.canvas.coords(box)[1] for box in self.boxes])
        return (0, level - (min_y // Tetris.BOX_SIZE))

    def predict_drop(self, board):
        level = self.__shape.drop(board, self.offset)
        self.remove_predicts()

        min_y = min([self.canvas.coords(box)[1] for box in self.boxes])
        for box in self.boxes:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.coords(box)
            box = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1,
                                               level * Tetris.BOX_SIZE + (y1 - min_y),
                                               x2,
                                               (level + 1) * Tetris.BOX_SIZE + (y1 - min_y),
                                               fill="yellow",
                                               tags = "predict")

    def remove_predicts(self):
        for i in self.canvas.find_withtag('predict'):
            self.canvas.delete(i) 
        self.canvas.update()

    def __create_boxes(self, start_point):
        boxes = []
        off_x, off_y = start_point
        for coord in self.__shape.coords:
            x, y = coord
            box = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x * Tetris.BOX_SIZE + off_x,
                                               y * Tetris.BOX_SIZE + off_y,
                                               x * Tetris.BOX_SIZE + Tetris.BOX_SIZE + off_x,
                                               y * Tetris.BOX_SIZE + Tetris.BOX_SIZE + off_y,
                                               fill="blue",
                                               tags="game")
            boxes += [box]

        return boxes

    def __can_move(self, box_coords, new_pos):
        x, y = new_pos
        x = x * Tetris.BOX_SIZE
        y = y * Tetris.BOX_SIZE
        x_left, y_up, x_right, y_down = box_coords

        overlap = set(self.canvas.find_overlapping((x_left + x_right) / 2 + x, 
                                                   (y_up + y_down) / 2 + y, 
                                                   (x_left + x_right) / 2 + x,
                                                   (y_up + y_down) / 2 + y))
        other_items = set(self.canvas.find_withtag('game')) - set(self.boxes)

        if y_down + y > Tetris.GAME_HEIGHT or \
           x_left + x < 0 or \
           x_right + x > Tetris.GAME_WIDTH or \
           overlap & other_items:
            # print("y_down + y > Tetris.GAME_HEIGHT : {}".format(y_down + y > Tetris.GAME_HEIGHT))
            # print("x_left + x < 0                  : {}".format(x_left + x < 0))
            # print("x_right + x > Tetris.GAME_WIDTH : {}".format(x_right + x > Tetris.GAME_WIDTH))
            # print("overlap & other_items           : {}".format(overlap & other_items))
            return False
        return True        

class Tetris():
    SHAPES = ([(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],     # Square
              [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)],     # Line
              [(2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)],     # Right L
              [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)],     # Left L
              [(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)],     # Right Z
              [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)],     # Left Z
              [(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)])     # T

    BOX_SIZE = 20

    GAME_WIDTH = 300
    GAME_HEIGHT = 500
    GAME_START_POINT = GAME_WIDTH / 2 / BOX_SIZE * BOX_SIZE - BOX_SIZE

    def __init__(self, predictable = False):
        self._level = 1
        self._score = 0
        self._blockcount = 0
        self.speed = 500
        self.predictable = predictable

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("500x550") 
        self.root.title('Tetris')
        self.root.bind("<Key>", self.game_control)
        self.__game_canvas()
        self.__level_score_label()
        self.__next_piece_canvas()

    def game_control(self, event):
        if event.char in ["a", "A", "\uf702"]:
            self.current_piece.move((-1, 0))
            self.update_predict()
        elif event.char in ["d", "D", "\uf703"]:
            self.current_piece.move((1, 0))
            self.update_predict()
        elif event.char in ["s", "S", "\uf701"]:
            self.hard_drop()
        elif event.char in ["w", "W", "\uf700"]:
            self.current_piece.rotate()
            self.update_predict()

    def new_game(self):
        self.level = 1
        self.score = 0
        self.blockcount = 0
        self.speed = 500

        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.next_canvas.delete("all")

        self.__draw_canvas_frame()
        self.__draw_next_canvas_frame()

        self.current_piece = None
        self.next_piece = None        

        self.game_board = [[0] * ((Tetris.GAME_WIDTH - 20) // Tetris.BOX_SIZE)\
                           for _ in range(Tetris.GAME_HEIGHT // Tetris.BOX_SIZE)]

        self.update_piece()

    def update_piece(self):
        if not self.next_piece:
            self.next_piece = Piece(self.next_canvas, (20,20))

        self.current_piece = Piece(self.canvas, (Tetris.GAME_START_POINT, 0), self.next_piece.shape)
        self.next_canvas.delete("all")
        self.__draw_next_canvas_frame()
        self.next_piece = Piece(self.next_canvas, (20,20))
        self.update_predict()

    def start(self):
        self.new_game()
        self.root.after(self.speed, None)
        self.drop()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def drop(self):
        if not self.current_piece.move((0,1)):
            self.current_piece.remove_predicts()
            self.completed_lines()
            self.game_board = self.canvas.game_board()
            self.update_piece()

            if self.is_game_over():
                return
            else:
                self._blockcount += 1
                self.score += 1

        self.root.after(self.speed, self.drop)

    def hard_drop(self):
        self.current_piece.move(self.current_piece.predict_movement(self.game_board))

    def update_predict(self):
        if self.predictable:
            self.current_piece.predict_drop(self.game_board)

    def update_status(self):
        self.status_var.set(f"Level: {self.level}, Score: {self.score}")
        self.status.update()

    def is_game_over(self):
        if not self.current_piece.move((0,1)):

            self.play_again_btn = Button(self.root, text="Play Again", command=self.play_again)
            self.quit_btn = Button(self.root, text="Quit", command=self.quit) 
            self.play_again_btn.place(x = Tetris.GAME_WIDTH + 10, y = 200, width=100, height=25)
            self.quit_btn.place(x = Tetris.GAME_WIDTH + 10, y = 300, width=100, height=25)
            return True
        return False

    def play_again(self):
        self.play_again_btn.destroy()
        self.quit_btn.destroy()
        self.start()

    def quit(self):
        self.root.quit()     

    def completed_lines(self):
        y_coords = [self.canvas.coords(box)[3] for box in self.current_piece.boxes]
        completed_line = self.canvas.completed_lines(y_coords)
        if completed_line == 1:
            self.score += 400
        elif completed_line == 2:
            self.score += 1000
        elif completed_line == 3:
            self.score += 3000
        elif completed_line >= 4:
            self.score += 12000

    def __game_canvas(self):
        self.canvas = GameCanvas(self.root, 
                             width = Tetris.GAME_WIDTH, 
                             height = Tetris.GAME_HEIGHT)
        self.canvas.pack(padx=5 , pady=10, side=LEFT)



    def __level_score_label(self):
        self.status_var = StringVar()        
        self.status = Label(self.root, 
                            textvariable=self.status_var, 
                            font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"))
        #self.status.place(x = Tetris.GAME_WIDTH + 10, y = 100, width=100, height=25)
        self.status.pack()

    def __next_piece_canvas(self):
        self.next_canvas = Canvas(self.root,
                                 width = 100,
                                 height = 100)
        self.next_canvas.pack(padx=5 , pady=10)

    def __draw_canvas_frame(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(10, 0, 10, self.GAME_HEIGHT, fill = "red", tags = "line")
        self.canvas.create_line(self.GAME_WIDTH-10, 0, self.GAME_WIDTH-10, self.GAME_HEIGHT, fill = "red", tags = "line")
        self.canvas.create_line(10, self.GAME_HEIGHT, self.GAME_WIDTH-10, self.GAME_HEIGHT, fill = "red", tags = "line")

    def __draw_next_canvas_frame(self):
        self.next_canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 90, 90, tags="frame")


    #set & get
    def __get_level(self):
        return self._level

    def __set_level(self, level):
        self.speed = 500 - (level - 1) * 25
        self._level = level
        self.update_status()

    def __get_score(self):
        return self._score

    def __set_score(self, score):
        self._score = score
        self.update_status()

    def __get_blockcount(self):
        return self._blockcount

    def __set_blockcount(self, blockcount):
        self.level = blockcount // 5 + 1
        self._blockcount = blockcount

    level = property(__get_level, __set_level)
    score = property(__get_score, __set_score)
    blockcount = property(__get_blockcount, __set_blockcount)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Tetris(predictable = True)
    game.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick answer, maybe I will add more things later (but I do not promise).

My suggestion for improvements is rather from the [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) standpoint:

- While your program seems doing the job, it has been hard for me to adapt my mind to the 4 control keys you use. It is more natural to use the arrow direction keys <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, and <kbd>←</kbd> in place of <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> respectively.
- For the rotation key, I would also prefer the arrow direction <kbd>↑</kbd> instead of <kbd>w</kbd>. This is good in case you decide to opt for the previous suggestion.
- The yellow indicator is  is a little noisy (and to be honest, it irritates me because somehow it confuses me). It would be good to remove it totally: after all, it is a factor that will impact the gamer who will have to focus where he has to place the corresponding shape.
- When the shape is a line, I noticed it is  drown a little out of the box (and cuts its right wall) where you display the levels and scores.
- I think you can still improve the colors you used: that red container is a little bit .... how to say ... even the blue and the background. I know this is subjective, but  subjectivity is a part of the user experience, especially when it comes to games.

But the overall is good, even better when we see  you managed to do that in tkinter. Good continuation.

Comment: I think I can agree on most points. I am not a game designer, so the UX is really flawed (I know). But, the predictable drop can be disabled by `game = Tetris(predictable = False)`. `False` is also the default.  Secondly, maybe it is preference, but `wasd` are my goto gaming keys :)

Comment: Yeah, I am sure you are going to focus more on the AI aspect of the game, UX is too subjective and you can not do it alone. For the keys, I understand what you mean, but coming back to the UX  world, I live in France, so my keyboard is AZERTY, not QWERTY, so it is not very easy for me to press `w` :)

Comment: The different layout of the keys didn't even cross my mind. Very good point, I will do a UX update eventually, but not that high on the priority list. Great answer nonetheless.